# C# Перенос валидации свойств класса в другой класс

Tags: c#, mvvm, валидация, properties, setter

Всем доброго времени суток).

Скажите, пожалуйста, допустим ли приведенный ниже подход при валидации полей класса. Суть подхода заключается в вынесении логики валидации полей класса из setter в методы класса-валидатора?

При использовании данного подхода можно будет менять правила валидации заданного класса. Кроме того, класс-валидатор можно будет повторно использовать в других участках программы, например при валидации ввода данных из окна программы (в ViewModel при использовании MVVM).

Пример реализации данного подхода для простого класса, хранящего информацию о книге. Мне приходилось сталкиваться с классами, в которых присутствует порядка 16 параметров, для каждого из которых задавалось свое правило проверки.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        IBookValidator bookValidator = new BookValidator();

        IBookInfo bookInfo = new BookInfo() {
            Author = "Толстой",
            Name = "Война и мир",
            Price = -1
        };

        try {
            Book book = new Book(bookInfo, bookValidator);
        }
        catch(ArgumentException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

// Книга
public class Book : IBook {
    public event EventHandler<IBookInfo> BookParamsUpdated;

    public double Price { get; private set; }
    public string Author { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Book(IBookInfo newBook, IBookValidator bookValidator) {
        // Пример проверки цены книги
        bool isParamsValid = bookValidator.Validate(newBook);

        if (isParamsValid == false) {
            // В упрощенном виде достаем текст ошибки
            throw new ArgumentException(bookValidator.Errors[0].Error);
        }
        else {
            Update(newBook);
        }
    }

    // Обновление параметров книги
    public void Update(IBookInfo bookData) {
        this.Price = bookData.Price;
        this.Author = bookData.Author;
        this.Name = bookData.Name;

        OnBookParamsUpdated();
    }

    private void OnBookParamsUpdated() {
        if (BookParamsUpdated != null) {
            BookParamsUpdated(this, new BookInfo(this));
        }
    }
}

// Параметры книги
public class BookInfo : IBookInfo {
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BookInfo() {

    }

    public BookInfo(IBookInfo bookInfo) {
        Price = bookInfo.Price;
        Author = bookInfo.Author;
        Name = bookInfo.Name;
    }
}

// Описывает параметры книги
public interface IBookInfo {
    double Price { get; }
    string Author { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

// Описывает книгу
public interface IBook : IBookInfo {
    void Update(IBookInfo bookInfo);

    event EventHandler<IBookInfo> BookParamsUpdated;
}

public class BookValidator : Validator<IBookInfo>, IBookValidator {
    public BookValidator() : base() {

    }

    // Проверяет параметры книги
    public override bool Validate( IBookInfo bookInfo ) {

        bool validResult = true;

        Errors.Clear();

        string errorPrice = "";
        bool validPrice = ValidatePrice( bookInfo.Price, out errorPrice);
        Errors.Add(new ValidationResult("Price", errorPrice));

        if (Errors.Count != 0) {
            validResult = false;
        }
        return validResult;
    }

    // Проверяет цену книги
    public bool ValidatePrice( double price, out string error) {

        bool isValid = true;
        error = "";
        if (price < 0) {
            error = "Стоимость книги < 0";
            isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}

// Описывает валидатор книги
public interface IBookValidator : IValidator<IBookInfo> {

    // Проверяет корректность стоимости книги
    bool ValidatePrice(double price, out string error);
}

// Результат валидации
public class ValidationResult {
    // Имя проверяемого параметра
    public string ParameterName { get; private set; }

    // Текст ошибки валидации
    public string Error { get; private set; }

    public ValidationResult(string parameterName, string errorMessage) {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
        Error = errorMessage;
    }
}

// Абстрактный Валидатор
public abstract class Validator<T> : IValidator<T> where T : class {
    public Validator() {
        Errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
    }

    // Список ошибок
    public List<ValidationResult> Errors { get; private set; }

    // Валидация объекта
    public abstract bool Validate(T objectForValidation);
}

// Описывает валидацию
public interface IValidator<T> where T : class {

    // Список ошибок валидации
    List<ValidationResult> Errors { get; }

    // Валидация
    bool Validate(T objectForValidation);
}
```

Comment: Ничего плохого в этом не вижу. Если логика валидации сложная, то почему бы ей и правда не сидеть в отдельном классе, чтобы не загромождать основной объект?

Comment: Согдасен с @VladD, только зачем валидатор вызывается в конструкторе? Почему бы не валидировать bookInfo до создания Book

Comment: VladD, tym32167, большое спасибо за ответы).
tym32167, внедрение я производил в конструктор, чтобы сразу задать правило валидации для объекта (валидатор присваивается приватному объекту с пометкой readonly). В дальнейшем валидация будет проводиться при использовании метода Update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный подход может вполне считаться удачным и иметь положительный эффект на структуру кода. Подобные практики даже описываются в некоторой литературе.

Например, Марк Симман, в книге "Внедрение зависимостей в .NET", описывает подобный подход, только реализуемый по средством шаблона Декоратор. В данном случае получается еще удобней, потому что клиентам класса нет необходимости знать о том, что происходит какая-либо валидация, плюс замена правила валидации при подобной реализации пройдет наиболее безболезненно

Comment: Большое спасибо, за ответ. Как раз сейчас активно погружен в изучение тем шаблонов проектирования и многослойной архитектуры (спасибо Мартину Фаулеру и Марку Симману за отличные книги. Как раз их изучаю. На их основе (плюс на основе пары тем со Stackowerflow) и возникла идея такой валидации).

Единственный момент, я думал подобную валидацию вводить для каждого класса модели, даже если логика проверки простая. Хочу это делать для единообразия). Может быть это и перегрузка, но будет соблюдено единообразие)

Comment: Смущает только то, что возможна злонамеренная подмена правил валидации в коде.

Comment: Для единообразия наверно нет смысла делать. Особенно если валидация простая или ее нет вовсе. Иначе получается, что с точки зрения ООП все верно, но может возникнуть такая вещь как "ООП ради ООП". Иными словами практической пользы от этого не будет, но разбирать код станет сложнее.  Далеко не все опытные программисты с этим согласятся. В общем, тут важен баланс.

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под злонамеренной подменой правил?

Comment: Под злонамеренной подменой правил я имел в виду следующее: допустим по техническому заданию заданы одни правила валидации. При каждом создании объекта класса Book эти правила загружаются в объект книги. Все хорошо. Но в другом месте программы злостный программист) загружает другие правила валидации. Хотя такое легко отследить. Просто немного смущает при таком подходе то, что правила жестко не зашиваются в объект, а выносятся за его пределы. Но мне такой подход нравится (Причины указал в тексте самого вопроса)

Comment: Насчет единообразия. Это не единственная причина. Просто не хочу в модели представления (ViewModel) дублировать правила валидации для соответствующих объектов. А так будет достаточно изменить правила в валидаторе. Хотя да, так будет сложнее читать код. Но здесь уже свои плюсы и минусы).

Comment: Согласен, тут дальше все на вкус и цвет. А на каждого злостного программиста найдется blame тулза)